# Docker FROM layer does not seem cached

Tags: docker

I was reading https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/ and it seems like all unchanged layers from the top will be cached.

I am using the same base image for multiple runs, but every time I do `docker build -t my-container .`, even without changes to the Dockerfile, it takes as long as it did the previous time to pull the base image (about 30 minutes).

What could be the reason for the base image not being cached?

Other than pulling the container from an internal registry, the simple Dockerfile I am using is something like this:

```
FROM openjdk:22-jdk
COPY . /usr/src/myapp
WORKDIR /usr/src/myapp
RUN javac Main.java
CMD ["java", "Main"]
```

Partial log output:

```
> docker build -t my-container .
[+] Building 1319.7s (5/8)
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.2s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                     0.3s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 336B                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for <image>                                                                                                                                     6.3s
 => [auth] <image>:pull token for <registry>                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [1/3] FROM <registry>/<image>@sha256:10bc31c03nm7c150b2f2553fc7afc658c2495214c262cbe47fb014020c24c9e3                                                                               1313.0s
 => => resolve <registry>/<image>:latest@sha256:10bc31c03nm7c150b2f2553fc7afc658c2495214c262cbe47fb014020c24c9e3                                                                                  0.4s
 => => sha256:10bc31c03nm7c150b2f2553fc7afc658c2495214c262cbe47fb014020c24c9e3 1.37kB / 1.37kB                                                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => sha256:f616452c03f1c6e4620f749a48f23cbc5c6c6078d1840cee93fdbb6ec71184e2 15.89kB / 15.89kB                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => sha256:b908537c6409239d2741043dce79199455e61a388c3abc3dfda849f3a67af982 231B / 231B                                                                                                                                               0.8s
 => => sha256:b35640c577f049266d491db188e821e49033f50105e85fc6d49f765f2bc151c5 281.02MB / 455.19MB                                                                                                                                    1312.4s
 => => extracting sha256:b908537c6409239d2741043dce79199455e61a388c3abc3dfda849f3a67af982                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.3s
 => => transferring context: 232B                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
```

If it matters, I'm on a Windows laptop using Docker desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, coming back to this after the weekend, I see that the unchanged layers *are* cached now.

```
> docker build -t my-container .
[+] Building 4.3s (8/8) FINISHED
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                     0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 269B                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for <registry>/<image>                                                                                                                                        3.7s
 => [auth] <image>:pull token for <registry>                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.1s
 => => transferring context: 87B                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [1/2]  FROM <registry>/<image>                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [2/2] COPY . /usr/src/myapp                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:b908537c6409239d2741043dce79199455e61a388c3abc3dfda849f3a67af982                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/my-container                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s
```

I'm not sure if this is because of insufficient space in the Docker Desktop. So while I only had about 1 GB free earlier (which would have been about 100 MB more than what this whole image requires), after clearing I had the whole 2 GB free again.

When I ran the docker build right after clearing out images from my Docker Desktop, it was able to retrieve the cached layer (which means it must have been cached even before I cleared my images).